# capture sound from mic and play it on speakers in c#

Tags: c#, audio, voice

I want to capture sound from mic and play it again in speakers in c# but not using Microsoft.DirectX.directsound how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to DirectSound there are the multi-media APIs. I know of no binding that's included with .net, but there are several third party bindings of varying quality.

[naudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is a popular .net audio library, but I don't know which API it uses in the background. As long as you avoid the abomination called `WaveBuffer` you should be fine.

In my project I used [Lumisoft.Audio](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Streaming_wave_audio.aspx?display=Mobile&fid=444913&df=90&mpp=10&noise=3&prof=True&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3761017&fr=31), mainly because it has a simple API. But their code doesn't have a very high quality.

Answer (score 0):

As CodeInChaos mentions NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com/) will do the trick. Here is an article from channel 9, which hopefully will help you out:

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder

This is from Mark Heath's NAudio demo (http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) as he mentions in this other post: [Capture a Microphone Audio Stream Using .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510019/capture-a-microphone-audio-stream-using-net-framework/510427#510427)