# Visual basic - Sound detection

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, audio

I am trying to make a program in Visual Basic .NET that is going to detect sound from the microphone input on my pc. The program is going to receive a series of beep sounds (sound/nosound) that is going to be translated in to binary data to create a file.

I have tried multiple codes to detect sound from the microphone and tried multiple codes to detect frequency and activity. But none of them work.

Is there any API/Library for .NET out there. Any old code which I can try to remake?
Really need this for my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture a Microphone Audio Stream Using .NET Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510019/capture-a-microphone-audio-stream-using-net-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the frequency part, but I do have something I use to detect volume coming in.  It's a C# project, but I compile it and then reference it from my VB.Net code.  Basically, I wait for a spike in sound and then perform an action when it occurs:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20503/LED-Style-Volume-Meter-Using-DirectX

It requires DirectX which is a large install so it may not be desirable (but, it will help with half of your problem).

You can also take a look at the NAudio project on CodePlex.  It has a lot of audio based code that a decent following.

http://naudio.codeplex.com/