# Get microphone input VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, volume, microphone, speech

How can I get the input volume of the microphone intro a progressbar?
I need to do this without an API if I can.
Thank You!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture a Microphone Audio Stream Using .NET Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510019/capture-a-microphone-audio-stream-using-net-framework)

Answer (score 1):

May I please direct your attention to [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder) article, which shows you how to use the nAudio dll to get input sound, and even shows you how to output it to a progressbar. It is in C#, but should be very easy to convert.