# Speech To Text Using MicroPhone

Tags: speech-to-text, microphone

In the Bing Speech API sample code, it mentioned "Input your own audio file or use read from a microphone stream directly.", but it didn't provide us any idea on how to read from a microphone stream directly. Any ideas? Thanks!   https://oxfordportal.blob.core.windows.net/speech/doc/recognition/Program.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture a Microphone Audio Stream Using .NET Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510019/capture-a-microphone-audio-stream-using-net-framework)