# C# How to stream microphone voice to HTTP?

Tags: c#

I can record voice from microphone and after this upload the .wav file to the http webserver.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

Public static void recorder()
{
    mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
}

Public static void stoprecord()
{
    mciSendString("save recsound " + file_output_name, "", 0, 0);
    mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
    Computer c = new Computer();
    c.Audio.Stop();
}
Public static void uploader()
{
    webclient wc = new webclient();
    wc.uploadfile("http://example.com/index.php", file_output_name);
}
```

But how can i stream  realtime voice to the http server?

Comment: Have a look at NAudio [Docs](https://naudio.codeplex.com/)/[Source](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). It allows you to get data from the mic as a stream.

Comment: Can you give me some example? :/

Comment: First you have to explain what format is the server expecting the stream to be in.

Comment: upvote just for using the correct rfc2606 domain.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/510019/156755. The author of the top answer has created an example and linked to it.